# Convert weight of food to volume in Wolfram Alpha

Tags: wolfram-alpha

How can I use the volume of food in equations on Wolfram Alpha?

For example, if I type: [`60g flour`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=60g+flour), I see that at the bottom, it says:

> serving volume: 3.5 fl oz.

How can I use this value in an equation to get the amount of cups, for example?

I want to be able to enter in a single query such as [`volume of 60g flour in cups`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=volume+of+60g+flour+in+cups). I have tried that query and several other combinations, but couldn't get any to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This one works: [`60 gramm/density of flour/cups`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=60+gramm/density+of+flour/cups)